# How to click image by camera in Android UI Automator?

Tags: android-uiautomator

I want to click an image using the android UI Automator for test cases but don't know how to find these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Done!!**

*Just replace the "com.sonyericsson.android.camera:id/center_container" by your own phone resource id*

mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.sonyericsson.android.camera:id/center_container")).click();